# Implementation of the word "вот" in different places

Tags: word

**вот** means **behold**

But, **вот офис** means **here is office**

So why **вот** is having different meanings in different places?

Comment: "Вот" does not mean "behold".

Comment: But google translate says so

Comment: I was sure you have this translation from Google translate :) But Google translate is not a dictionary. It's much better to have a real dictionary when you learn a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to point on something or somebody `вот офис` - here is the office (point to office with your hand or say at the end of excursion), `вот зефир` - here is the marshmallow (point to marshmallow with your hand or give somebody a plate with marshmallow), `вот эта девушка` here is the girl (show the girl on a smartphone), `вот, возьми чашку в шкафу` - take the cap in the cupboard (point to the cupboard with hand).

As an amplification (maybe this meaning is not much different from the first) `а вот мой пирог вкуснее` or `вот мой пирог вкуснее` - and my pie is more tasty.

As a filler word at the end of **any** sentence, but it is treated as if you are bad speaker or a kid: `Я голодный. Вот.` - I am hungry.

`Вот ты сказал неправду сейчас` - you have lied now. You can say this without `Вот` and `сейчас` or use only one of them - the are amplifiers at this case.

Also `Пожалуйста, внимание. Вот наш новый программист` - Attention please, here is our new programmer (two persons have entered the room with coworkers) and `вот наш новый программист сказал, что ты не прав` - and our new programmer said that you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Вот is an adverb, can be usually translated as "here", but usually does not have the meaning of physical proximity as "тут" and "здесь", but rather means the thing in question is in the range of sight.